# How to post image on server with dictionary iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, http-post, nsdictionary

I have a `dictionary (dict)` of some keys/values and an `image`. Now I want to upload image to server with dictionary. I have already try this but not getting any success. Here is my sample code--

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.5);//or you can use png representation- UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"thumbnail\"; filename=\"image.png\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:imageData];

[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//  parameter all_data
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"all_data\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dict] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// close form
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the request
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSError *error=nil;
NSHTTPURLResponse *response=nil;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

I need help where is I'm going wrong.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine but I think you have to convert your dictionary into `json string`. Just Replace this line-

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dict] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

with

```
NSString *jsonStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[body appendData:[jsonStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

may be this will help you.

Comment: Happy to help you:) If answer finds helpful then please mark it as accepted. So other users will find it helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try out the below code:

```
    -(void)uploadImage:(NSString *)api :(NSDictionary *)params : (UIImage *)image {

    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:api];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:myURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@; charset=UTF-8", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSMutableData *theBodyData = [NSMutableData data];
    for (int i=0; i<[[params allKeys] count]; i++)
    {
        [theBodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSString *value=@"";
        value=[params objectForKey:[[params allKeys] objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSString * value1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=%@\r\n\r\n%@\r\n",[[params allKeys] objectAtIndex:i],value];
        [theBodyData appendData:[value1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    [theBodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [theBodyData appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"my_file1\"; filename=\"image1.jpeg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

    [theBodyData appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    NSData *myData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.5);
    [theBodyData appendData:[NSData dataWithData:myData]];

    [theBodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



    [request setHTTPBody:theBodyData];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)[theBodyData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody: theBodyData];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if(error == nil) {
            NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Server Raw Response : %@",responseString);
        }

    }];

    [dataTask resume];


}
```